# Can only transfer photos from Moto X to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, pdf, mtp

I have a Moto X and use Ubuntu 14.04, as far as I know 14.04 has mtp support in addition to the mtp-tools I installed but for some reason I can only transfer photos from my phone to my pc.

When I try to open a .pdf it displays an error of `could not open` (using Okular), when I try to copy the .pdf to my desktop it shows `Error getting file: -6: Not Supported`, when I try to open a .mp3 it doesn't play and when I try to copy it to my desktop I get `Error getting file: -1: Unspecified error` and freezes my desktop. In addition to that, if I try to open an .mp3 file and then a photo I get `Failed to open input stream for file`.

Any clue as to how to solve this? I just need to get my .pdf, I don't care much about the music. (I've tried setting up an FTPserver but still got the same errors)

Edit: forgot to mention I can transfer files and open them right away but if I unplug my phone and reconnect they're no longer accessible.